# Extract as Numbers from a String to Calculate

Tags: r

I have a vector as below

```
data <- c("6X75ML","24X37.5ML(KKK)", "6X2X75ML", "168X5CL (UUU)", "168X5CLKK (BUU)")
```

The above data is basically pack sizes of bottles in a case. What it means is in case of "6X75ML" there are 6 bottles of 75CL (Centi liters) liquid each. For "6X2X75ML" which is basically a promotion pack has 6X2 = 12 bottles of 75ML (Milli liters) in a case.
I need to find the volume in liters available in each case:
e.g -

`"6X75ML"` should be `(6 * 75 * 0.001) = 0.45` Liters

`"24X37.5ML(KKK)"` should be `(6 * 37.5 * 0.001) = 0.9` Liters

`"6X2X75ML"` should be `(6 * 2 * 75 * 0.001) = 0.9` Liters

[there can only be a maximum of 3 digits between the X]

Conversions:
ML - Milli liters
CL - Centi liters
LTR - Liters

```
1ML = 0.001LTR
1CL = 0.01LTR
```

In some cases as in the above there could be values like "168X5CLKK (BUU)" where only CL needs to be taken.

## I have the below code helping me to find the quantity of bottles in a case

```
dataList <- strsplit(data, split="X")
Pack <- sapply(dataList, function(x) prod(as.numeric(head(x, -1))))
```

eg. "6X2X75ML" ll give 12; "168X5CL (UUU)" ll give 168 etc

Working:
strplit breaks up the vector along "X". The resulting list is fed to sapply which the performs an operation on all but the final element of each vector in the list. The operation is to transform the elements into numeric s and the multiply them. The final element is dropped using head(x, -1).

I am not able to find a way around the an efficient way to split the last element to get the volume.

Comment: Does the (KKK) or (UUU) mean anything? You could use regex to strip out anything in parenthesis. Then you can use the second-to-last character to determine what 10^n you want to multiply by. (M, C, or T)

Comment: You should fix your example. You have `"6X75CL"` in the text but `"6X75ML"` in the data.

Comment: Hi all, can any wone check with a few other examples like : "6X180CL (LMD)" , "6X75CL (JIH) (DELIST)". It does not seems to work here.

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- c("6X75ML","24X37.5ML(KKK)", "6X2X75ML", "168X5CL (UUU)", "168X5CLKK (BUU)")
```

Replace ML with X0.001

```
data <- gsub("ML", "X0.001", data)
```

Replace CL with X0.01

```
data <- gsub("CL", "X0.01", data)
```

split the string and do the multiplication

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(gsub("[A-Z() ]*$", "", data), "X"), function(x){ prod(as.numeric(x))}))
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.45 0.90 0.90 8.40 8.40
```

Comment: The output does not match the example

Comment: Adding a space in the regex will fix it

Comment: In your previous answer, switching `"[A-Z()]*$"` for `"[A-Z() ]*$"` would've produced the desired output.

Comment: It is still incorrect. Just do the math by hand `24*37.5*0.001 [1] 0.9`. It's easy to check your answers

Comment: All we have to go on is the description. They are converting measurements to liters. "ML" is 0.001 Liters, and so on.

Comment: Shouldn't the last two be `8.4`? They have `CL` attached

Comment: Hi all, I believe its working ... the problem was on the conversion factor 0.1 and 0.01... need to put in 0.01 and 0.001

Comment: Thanks all ... it has been a great help.... everyone has basically saved 100's on man hours of effort for n number of people.....

Comment: Hi all, can any wone check with a few other examples like : "6X180CL (LMD)" , "6X75CL (JIH) (DELIST)". It does not seems to work here.

Comment: The question has an inconsistency. The given vector is `data <- c("6X75ML","24X37.5ML(KKK)", "6X2X75ML", "168X5CL (UUU)", "168X5CLKK (BUU)")`, but in the example calculations the OP asks for 6 * `75CL` instead of `75ML (as specified in the given vector).`Just correct the vector and the code gives you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sathish solution is straightforward.

If you would require to extract and store the volume and number of bottles, you could also use this code:

```
# Data
data <- c("6X75ML","24X37.5ML(KKK)", "6X2X75ML", "168X5CL (UUU)", "168X5CLKK (BUU)")


# (1) Calculate volume per unit/bottle
# ------------

# Get volume measurement: 
# Extract bottle volume and define conversion factor
bottle.volumes.units <- substr(sub(".*X[0-9,.]+", "", data), 0, 2)
bottle.volumes.in.liter <- gsub("ML", 0.001, bottle.volumes.units)
bottle.volumes.in.liter <- gsub("CL", 0.01, bottle.volumes.in.liter)

# Get volume per bottle
# All numbers in every vector
all.numbers <- regmatches(data, gregexpr('\\(?[0-9,.]+', data))
# The volume information for each bottle
bottle.volumes <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(all.numbers, last)))

# Harmonize volume measuremet to "liters"
bottle.volumes.in.liters <- as.numeric(bottle.volumes.in.liter) * bottle.volumes


# (2) Get the number of units/bottles
# ------------
number.of.bottles.temp <- lapply(all.numbers, function(x)as.numeric(setdiff(x, as.list(bottle.volumes))))
number.of.bottles <- sapply(number.of.bottles.temp, prod)


# (3) Calculate volume
# ------------
number.of.bottles * bottle.volumes.in.liters

# [1] 0.45 0.90 0.90 8.40 8.40
```